# Wrong query, Error " Wrong syntax near the SET Statement "

Tags: c#, sql

What is the wrong thing in this code

```
String updateCmd = String.Format(@"UPDATE [admins] 
    SET [authority type] = '{0}', 
    SET [signature] = N'{1}', 
    SET [message] = N'{2}' 
    WHERE '{3}'", authorityType, signature, msg, condition);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should only use one `SET` clause on `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE [admins] 
SET [authority type] = '{0}',
    [signature] = N'{1}', 
    [message] = N'{2}' 
WHERE '{3}'
```

one more thing, please do parameterized your query to avoid `SQL Injection`. use `Command` Object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat `SET`

```
 String updateCmd = String.Format("UPDATE [admins] SET [authority type] = '{0}',
                    [signature] = N'{1}',  [message] = N'{2}' WHERE '{3}'", 
                    authorityType, signature, msg, condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need multiple set just one.